# JAXB namespace only to some of the tags

Tags: java, xml, soap, jaxb

I have a SOAP endpoint that I need to consume. The java code generation is done with maven plugin - wsimport. The problem is that the endpoint returns bad data with otherwise valid requests. Here is an example of the request that passes:

```
<soapenv:Envelope     
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:upd="http://www.vivacom.bg/UpdateBAInvoiceInfo/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <upd:UpdBAInvoiceInfoRequest>
         <BillingAccountCode>10122190001</BillingAccountCode>
         <SSOGUID>1234567</SSOGUID>
         <RequestedInvoiceType>E</RequestedInvoiceType>
         <eMail1>govcharov@abv.bg</eMail1>
         <InputRequestID>SSS0123456789</InputRequestID>
         <InputTimeStamp>20170202131615154</InputTimeStamp>
      </upd:UpdBAInvoiceInfoRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

here the "upd" prefix is defined in the top level. However, the JAXB generates this request:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <UpdBAInvoiceInfoRequest 
 xmlns="http://www.vivacom.bg/UpdateBAInvoiceInfo/">
            <BillingAccountCode>10122190001</BillingAccountCode>
            <SSOGUID>1234567</SSOGUID>
            <RequestedInvoiceType>E</RequestedInvoiceType>
            <eMail1>govcharov@abv.bg</eMail1>
            <InputRequestID>NMS2081417920</InputRequestID>
            <InputTimeStamp>20170202131615154</InputTimeStamp>
        </UpdBAInvoiceInfoRequest>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

The "upd" qualifier is missing and the xmlns is embedded in the tag. After modifying the package-info.java manually and adding Xmlns prefix

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = 
"http://www.vivacom.bg/UpdateBAInvoiceInfo/",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED,
        attributeFormDefault = XmlNsForm.UNSET,
        xmlns = {
                @XmlNs(prefix="upd", 
namespaceURI="http://www.vivacom.bg/UpdateBAInvoiceInfo/")
        })
```

The request that is generated adds "upd" prefix to all the elements and results in "BadData" again, because the elements are not defined in the namespace but are embedded for the type.

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
    <S:Body>
        <upd:UpdBAInvoiceInfoRequest 
xmlns:as="http://www.vivacom.bg/UpdateBAInvoiceInfo/">

<upd:BillingAccountCode>10122190001</upd:BillingAccountCode>
            <upd:SSOGUID>1234567</upd:SSOGUID>
            <upd:RequestedInvoiceType>E</upd:RequestedInvoiceType>
            <upd:eMail1>govcharov@abv.bg</upd:eMail1>
            <upd:InputRequestID>NMS2513334601</upd:InputRequestID>
<upd:InputTimeStamp>20170202131615154</upd:InputTimeStamp>
        </upd:UpdBAInvoiceInfoRequest>
    </S:Body>
 </S:Envelope>
```

I need to add "upd" before BillingAccountCode, but not before its attributes.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of trying out different solutions, I found the answer a couple minutes after posting the question... 
I changed the elementFormDefault to XmlNsForm.UNSET from XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED and it produced exactly what I need. Now I need to make wsimport maven plugin generate package-info.java file this way.

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
        namespace = "http://www.vivacom.bg/UpdateBAInvoiceInfo/",
        elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.UNSET)
```